# How to create molecule bondings movement using chemfig and animate package

Tags: chemfig, animate

I wanted to have a simple way of showing moving atoms within a molecule structure. I was inspired by this website: [http://chem.libretexts.org](http://chem.libretexts.org/Core/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry/Spectroscopy/Vibrational_Spectroscopy/Vibrational_Modes). Here's one example of how to create that. Others may add more examples later on.

Comment: Oh, a call for an `animate` showcase? I am flattered :-).

Comment: Yes, that's the price you'll have to pay for giving me so much help! :-)

Comment: Wow, just realized you're the developer behind [tag:animate]! I love it a ton.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
%
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[loop,palindrome,autoplay]{animate}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setatomsep{3em}
\centering
Symmetric stretching

\newline

\begin{animateinline}[begin={\begin{minipage}[c][3em][c]{8em}}, end={\end{minipage}}]{3}
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\chemfig{C(=[:-180,1.2]O)(=[:0,1.2]O)}
}
\newframe
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\chemfig{C(=[:-180,0.95]O)(=[:0,0.95]O)}
}
\newframe
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\chemfig{C(=[:-180,0.65]O)(=[:0,0.65]O)}
}
\end{animateinline}

Antisymmetric stretching

\newline

\begin{animateinline}[begin={\begin{minipage}[c][3em][c]{8em}}, end={\end{minipage}}]{3}
\noindent\makebox[7em][c]{
\chemfig{C(=[:-180,1.25]O)(=[:0,0.75]O)}
}
\newframe
\noindent\makebox[8em][c]{
\chemfig{C(=[:-180,1]O)(=[:0,1]O)}
}
\newframe
\noindent\makebox[9em][c]{
\chemfig{C(=[:-180,0.7]O)(=[:0,1.2]O)}
}
\end{animateinline}

Scissoring (bending)

\newline

\begin{animateinline}[begin={\begin{minipage}[c][6em][c]{8em}}, end={\end{minipage}}]{3}
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\chemfig{C(<[:165])(<:[:195])(-[:-30]H)(-[:30]H)}
}
\newframe
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\chemfig{C(<[:165])(<:[:195])(-[:-45]H)(-[:45]H)}
}
\newframe
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\chemfig{C(<[:165])(<:[:195])(-[:-60]H)(-[:60]H)}
}
\end{animateinline}

Rocking

\newline

\begin{animateinline}[begin={\begin{minipage}[c][5em][c]{8em}}, end={\end{minipage}}]{3}
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\chemfig{C(<[:165])(<:[:195])(-[:30]H)(-[:90]H)}
}
\newframe
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\chemfig{C(<[:165])(<:[:195])(-[:0]H)(-[:60]H)}
}
\newframe
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\chemfig{C(<[:165])(<:[:195])(-[:-30]H)(-[:30]H)}
}
\newframe
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\chemfig{C(<[:165])(<:[:195])(-[:-60]H)(-[:0]H)}
}
\newframe
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\chemfig{C(<[:165])(<:[:195])(-[:-90]H)(-[:-30]H)}
}
\end{animateinline}

Wagging

\newline

\begin{animateinline}[begin={\begin{minipage}[c][7em][c]{8em}}, end={\end{minipage}}]{3}
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\chemfig{C(<[:165])(<:[:195])(<[:-30,1.5]{\mbox{\Huge H}})(<[:30,1.5]{\mbox{\Huge H}})}
}
\newframe
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\chemfig{C(<[:165])(<:[:195])(<[:-30,1.25]{\mbox{\Large H}})(<[:30,1.25]{\mbox{\Large H}})}
}
\newframe
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\chemfig{C(<[:165])(<:[:195])(-[:-30]{\mbox{\normalsize H}})(-[:30]{\mbox{\normalsize H}})}
}
\newframe
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\chemfig{C(<[:165])(<:[:195])(<:[:-30]{\mbox{\footnotesize H}})(<:[:30]{\mbox{\footnotesize H}})}
}
\newframe
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\chemfig{C(<[:165])(<:[:195])(<:[:-30]{\mbox{\tiny H}})(<:[:30]{\mbox{\tiny H}})}
}
\end{animateinline}


Twisting

\newline

\begin{animateinline}[begin={\begin{minipage}[c][6em][c]{8em}}, end={\end{minipage}}]{3}
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\chemfig{C(<[:165])(<:[:195])(<[:-30,1.5]{\mbox{\Huge H}})(<:[:30]{\mbox{\tiny H}})}
}
\newframe
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\chemfig{C(<[:165])(<:[:195])(<[:-30,1.25]{\mbox{\Large H}})(<:[:30]{\mbox{\footnotesize H}})}
}
\newframe
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\chemfig{C(<[:165])(<:[:195])(-[:-30]{\mbox{\normalsize H}})(-[:30]{\mbox{\normalsize H}})}
}
\newframe
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\chemfig{C(<[:165])(<:[:195])(<:[:-30]{\mbox{\footnotesize H}})(<[:30,1.25]{\mbox{\Large H}})}
}
\newframe
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\chemfig{C(<[:165])(<:[:195])(<:[:-30]{\mbox{\tiny H}})(<[:30,1.5]{\mbox{\Huge H}})}
}
\end{animateinline}

\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Output example

[image: OutputExample]

Comment: The code compiles only if I comment out the `\newlines`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this answer involves chemistry after a fashion...and its concomitant influence on biology.  And I didn't even need to use `chemfig`.

Anyone with a teenage daughter can relate...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[loop,palindrome,autoplay]{animate}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\char80\char77\char83:
\begin{animateinline}[begin={\begin{minipage}[c][6em]{12em}}, end={\end{minipage}}]{3}
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{-1.0pt}{\scalebox{2.4}[2.6]{$\cap$}}{%
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{2.0}[2.6]{$\cap$}}{%
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{1pt}{\scalebox{.5}{$\circ$}\,\scalebox{.5}{$\circ$}}{%
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{-3pt}{\scalebox{1}[.9]{$\circ$}}{%
  \LARGE\sffamily O}}}}
}
\newframe
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{-1.0pt}{\scalebox{2.4}[2.6]{$\cap$}}{%
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{2.0}[2.6]{$\cap$}}{%
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{1pt}{\scalebox{.3}{$\circ$}\,\scalebox{.3}{$\circ$}}{%
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{-3pt}{\scalebox{1}[.7]{$\circ$}}{%
  \LARGE\sffamily O}}}}
}
\newframe
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{-1.0pt}{\scalebox{2.4}[2.6]{$\cap$}}{%
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{2.0}[2.6]{$\cap$}}{%
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{1pt}{..}{%
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{-3pt}{\scalebox{1}[.5]{$\circ$}}{%
  \LARGE\sffamily O}}}}
}
\newframe
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{-1.0pt}{\scalebox{2.4}[2.6]{$\cap$}}{%
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{2.0}[2.6]{$\cap$}}{%
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{1pt}{..}{%
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{-3pt}{-}{%
  \LARGE\sffamily O}}}}
}
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```